# Unable to send and retrieve data to Database (PHP/MySQL/Android)

Tags: php, android, mysql

I've been studying this PHP-MySQL-Android Login system, and after debugging some code issues, it seems that I got the PHP code to communicate to the Database succesfully. I confirmed that via PostMan, where I was able to input data and retrieve it (running the register and login php files).

However, running from my app in Android Studio I'm not able to do it. It won't give me code errors and it runs fine, but still, data is not going to the database for some reason. And if I manually insert data to it and then try to Login using the App, it won't work as well. I am probably missing something basic here that I'm unable to see for myself. Can anyone help me where and how I should look at it to see what might be going wrong? Again, using PostMan I'm able to Register and Login with the current php files I have, so does that mean that my problem is 100% in my Java code in Android Studio?

Thanks everyone!

Here's my RegisterActivity and RegisterRequest:

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "my url is here";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String username, String email, String passcode, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();

    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("email", email);
    params.put("passcode", passcode);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}


public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_register);


    final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(id.etEmail);
    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(id.etPassword);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            final String passcode = etPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("OMG");
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username, email, passcode, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here's my LoginRequest and LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "my url is here";
private Map<String, String> params;

public LoginRequest(String username, String passcode, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("passcode", passcode);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final TextView tvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);
    final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignIn);

    tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });

    assert bLogin != null;
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String passcode = etPassword.getText().toString();

            // Response received from the server
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            String username = jsonResponse.getString("username");
                            String email = jsonResponse.getString("email");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("username", username);
                            intent.putExtra("email", email);
                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, passcode, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here's my Register.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "my server is here";
$username = "my username";
$password = "my password";
$dbname = "my db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO User (username, email, passcode) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $email, $passcode);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$passcode = $_POST["passcode"];

$stmt->execute();

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();   



?>
```

Here's my Login.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "my server is here";
$username = "my username";
$password = "my password";
$dbname = "my db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$passcode = $_POST["passcode"];

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND passcode = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $passcode);

$stmt->execute(); 

mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $userID, $username, $email, $passcode);


 $response = array();
 $response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    $response["success"] = true;  

    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["passcode"] = $passcode;
}


echo json_encode($response);

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();


?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Never store passwords as plain-text. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and use a function like [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to properly encode them.

Comment: thanks tadman! I understand, working with encryption comes next, at this point I would like to at least understand and have the basic functionality working!

Answer (score 0):

Well what you know... I tried in Genymotion (I was running it with the AS default emulators) and it worked!

Now, I don't know why it did not on the default emulators...